# How can we run Selenium tests on selenoid in jmeter?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, selenoid

I am using Selenoid in place of the Selenium grid. I have used Remote Driver Config in my Jmeter, but I am not able to debug a failure in the script. How can I provide additional capabilities such as enableVideo, enableVNC, and enable logs for remote browsers on selenoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current [version 3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.3) of the WebDriver Sampler Plugin the "capabilities" list is hard-coded inside the [RemoteDriverConfig](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/RemoteDriverConfig.java#L26) class so the options are in:

1. Amend the source of the aformentioned class according to your needs, re-build the plugin and replace the .jar in the "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation with the newly built one
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). On one hand it will give you the full freedom when it comes to configuring and launching the webdriver instance(s), but on the other hand you will need to take care of multithreading-related constraints yourself